# How to print first value in a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with one key and multiple values associated with that key. So it looks like this:

```
{'key': ['value', 'value', 'value', 'value']}
```

How can I get my program to print just the first value?

Answer (score 4):

The corresponding *value* is a `list`, so to access to an element in an specific position of a `list`, you can use an index. The syntax is:

```
some_list[index]
```

In your case, you have to get the `value` corresponding to `key` from the dictionary, using:

```
x['key']  # list
```

And to access to its first element, use the syntax explained above:

```
x['key'][0] # first element of the list
```

**Note:** In most programming languages, indices start with `0`. So the first element will be in the index `0`, the second in the index `1`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = {'key': ['value','value','value','value']} 
print x['key'][0]
```

Comment: That's OK, but if you want to become any good, you should read some Python tutorials, and try all the examples out.